# In induced pluripotency experiments, what happens to the cells that do not become pluripotent?

Tags: genetics, molecular-biology, cell-biology, stem-cells

I am new to this topic, so forgive me if my question is naïve. In an induced pluripotency experiment a few transcription factors are overexpressed in somatic cells and as a result a small portion of the cells become pluripotent (fully or partially), but the vast majority of the cells do not. My question is this: what does happen to these cells (the ones that do not become pluripotent) in terms of gene expression levels? Do gene expression profiles of these cells remain unchanged (the same before and after overexpression of the pluripotency factors)? Or do they change and become something that is different from both pluripotent cells and the original somatic cells?